# 'android:launchMode="singleInstance"' does not allow activity for results update

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, single-instance

When setting to a single instance, the Activity does not allow another Activity to update it using the Activity for results method. What is the flag I should set so that I do not have to remove the initial launch mode as single instance?

Note: I am using another activity as an image loader, that updates the launcher activity.
Launcher activity should be a single instance, because I am using it to notify using the status bar.

This is a challenge, so I can not use another activity for notifications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366992/startactivityforresult-not-working-properly-with-launchmode-singleinstance

Comment: thanks, I found that before your posted comment. Next time I will search more thoroughly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, even I faced the same problem. That's why I was not able to use Activity for results with the launch mode as a single instance as I found I get the call on onActivityResult as the acivity B starts.