# startActivityForResult returning instantly without the correct result

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the [facebook sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) to log the user in.

I call an activity I've created that only does the facebook login and should return a result back to the original activity.

Here is how I'm calling this (it's from the inside of a custom component, that's why the `getContext()` is used):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FacebookAuthenticationActivity.class);
Log.d(TAG, "Starting facebook authentication for result");
((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FACEBOOK);
```

And here I want the response:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Result from something!");
    if(requestCode == LoginWidget.REQUEST_FACEBOOK) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Result from facebook received!");
            mLoginWidget.onFacebookLoginSucceeded(intent);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

On the facebook activity, it's the code from the [facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso). There is no error in that code... For some weird reason the activity calls the `onActivityResult` before he calls the `onCreate` on the `FacebookAuthActivity`.

The coode I've written is to log the user in, get some info and finally call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("user_json", response);

Log.d(TAG, "Setting result to: " + intent);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

After reviewing the logs here is what I get:

```
07-11 16:34:27.992: D/LoginWidget(6863): Starting facebook authentication for result
07-11 16:34:27.992: D/ProgramActivity(6863): I am starting an activity to get a result!
07-11 16:34:28.101: D/ProgramActivity(6863): Result from something!
07-11 16:34:40.875: D/Facebook-authorize(6863): Login Success! access_token=xxx expires=1347195352881
07-11 16:34:40.875: D/FacebookAuthentication(6863): User accepted our app in facebook!
07-11 16:34:42.351: D/FacebookAuthentication(6863): Setting result to: Intent { (has extras) }
```

So I am out of ideas... For some reason when I call this activity it immediately calls `onActivityResult` on the parent without the result, then after that, it logs in, sets the real result, calls finish, and never calls `onActivityResult` with the real response.

Am I missing something here? Do I have to set a specific flag for this activity to correctly return me the result?

It's just a simple activity with a bunch of async facebook calls and then calls back with the result...

**UPDATE**

Just to be clearer, I do not get any errors from this code. The problem is that when I set the result, after the login, the originating activity does not receive the result.

Comment: remove the call to super.onActivityResult

Comment: @Orlymee check the question, updated it

Comment: possible solution : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744247/check-user-action-on-intent-action-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366992/startactivityforresult-not-working-properly-with-launchmode-singleinstance). This "feature" does not allow activities started using `singleInstace` to call activities for results.

I changed my activity to `singleTop` and it now works as it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your example neither set an Action/Uri nor a package context/class for that intend.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent()

You must set either one of those two, i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("xxx://someUri");
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

Where `MyActivity.class` is the name/type of the Activity which should process something and return the result.

Comment: I do set that for the request to create the activity, it's in the question. I don't set that on the result setting, because I don't have another activity to start, the intent is the result bundle.