# Handling startActivityForResult() with proper return code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a test app which will launch the intents of different player application from within.

Tried something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/1234.mp4");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setClassName("com.android.gallery3d","com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent, ON_COMPLETION);
```

I understand that ***startActivityForResult()*** will trigger a callback once the launched intent has finished it job. As expected in the ***onActivityResult()*** implementation I am receiving a completion notification.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    Log.i(TAG,"onActivityResult with resultCode " + resultCode + "requestCode" + requestCode);
```

}

But, my question is I am getting the resultCode as "ZERO" always i.e. resultCode = **RESULT_CANCELED** even if the playback is successful or even if I specify a invalid file name while launching the intent.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rtcdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rtcdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here are my questions:
1. How can we handle better the onCompletion event ? i.e the return state of the launched intent, whether the playback is successful or its a fail.
2. If this is not the right way to implement, can you please guide me to the right set of tutorial where I can get some sample code ?

My objective is the launch intents of multiple media player app like Gallery, MX player and VLC and get to know whether the playback of the file is successful or not for the clip specified.

I am newbie and some suggestions on this topic will be more helpful.

Comment: are you sure the the requestCode is the same with the ON_COMPLETION ?

Comment: Yes. I am getting the requestCode same as ON_COMPLETION, but the resultCode as zero.

Comment: the activity you use to view your video does not care about sending you a result code. there is nothing you can do to change that, short of reimplementing the view activity yourself.

Comment: Thank you @njzk2. your answer makes sense .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in Android Developer on [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

> In other protocols (such as ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not
>   get the result when you expect.

You can't count on action views returning what you would expect,so what i did was implement a custom alert dialog that shows all possible applications that can open a certain file,a slightly modified version as shown here [Custom intent chooser](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.it/2012/01/creating-custom-android-intent-chooser.html)

[more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746095/2401265)

**UPDATE**

after a little more search i found [that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/0b22712/src/com/android/gallery3d/app), you can see various of classes, but the important thing is that the class you are calling with the intent doesn't changing the return value.
You are calling MovieActivity that extends Activity not ActivityState. 
In the Abstract class [ActivityState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/0b22712/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/ActivityState.java) the value is changing and it returns. Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: thank you for pointing out a link. I feel its not startActivityForResult() or its callback. It would be great if you can point to some other helpful links. thanks in advance.