# how to pass a callback in activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two Activity: Activity1 and Activity2
Activity1 start Activity2 and I want to send a result from Activity2 to Activity1, but I can't use startActivityForResult() cause the lanuchmode of Activity1 is singelInstance. Are there any ways to send a callback from Activity1 to Activity2?(So far as I konw, one is send BroadCaseReceiver, the other is made a static param in Activity2)

Many thanks!

Comment: You could set up a "Handler" to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

[startActivityForResult not working properly with launchMode singleInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366992/startactivityforresult-not-working-properly-with-launchmode-singleinstance)

A similar question, it suggested using saved instance state and or saving information to a db/global storage.

[onActivityResult do not fire if launch mode of activity is singleInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118525/onactivityresult-do-not-fire-if-launch-mode-of-activity-is-singleinstance)

Proposes that you use a different type, replacing singleInstance with singleTask

You could extend the activity you want to launch and force its type to a different one for this scenario, leaving the original as SingleInstance.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work to use broadcast to communicate between two Activities. Only one of the Activities will ever be active at a time. It does make sense to use it to communicate between an Activity and a Service, for example.

Generally you can use intent extras to pass information to the next Activity. I.e, using putExtra.

(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

Comment: I tried extra, there is one question: I can get the callback from extra in Activity2, but getApplicationContext() is null cause this extra is from Activity1 and Activity1 is in onStop state.